How to make TalkBack read the spelling of Chinese characters in terms of the names of the Chinese character components
When a blind user is using TalkBack to listen to text, they may want to figure out the actual spelling of the text.
Can TalkBack be used to spell a Chinese character or stream of Chinese characters in terms of Chinese radical or Chinese character component names, so that the blind user may know what the characters that are being read out are made of? How can this be enabled in Android?

Talkback already states support for Chinese (China) and Chinese (Taiwan) as shown in https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/11101402?hl=en-GB and assumes that the user is a native speaker. If you are learning Chinese you should look into apps for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin (with the usual disclaimer that software recommendations are off-topic here)
